# can't find directory and file created with ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

So I downloaded ubunto to start working with command line. It seems ubuntu created a directory that it named my username in my desktop (as discovered via pwd). I since created a file called colors.txt file using nano just for some practice. Using the ls command confirmed I created colors.txt.

However, I cannot find a folder that is called my username, or the file called colors.text anywhere on my computer. Is this normal? Where could this directory and colors.txt be?

Comment: Please edit your question and copy - paste commands you run in terminal.

Comment: "on my computer" means what exactly? Where are you trying to find it? You say you find it in the terminal, thus you should know the directory you're looking for is probably /home/your-user-name/. Any file manager application should be able to show it.

Comment: Your username-folder should not be IN the Desktop folder, it should be like this:  `/home/yourusername/Desktop`.  If `colors.txt` is in your Desktop folder, you should see on your desktop.

Comment: The directory is /home/my-user-name/. I've searched the desktop and my PC but haven't found my-user-name directory or the file I created there

Answer (score 0):

Use the find command

```
find . -iname "colours.*" -print
```

the . after the find is to specify the start directory (in this case the current). For example to search the Designs directory

```
find Documents/Designs -iname "colours.*" -print
```

the '-iname' ignores case, and will match

- Colours.txt
- colours.txt
- CoLoUrs.txt

Use '-name' to be strict about names

The -print says what action is is redundant, so you could leave it out.

You could user other actions, for example

```
find . -iname "colours.*" -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first change the directory to be able to see your files on your desktop.

On your Ubuntu Command line follow the steps-

Step 1 - First go to root directory. `cd /`

Step 2 - Then look for directory by the name mnt and select that directory. `ls` `cd mnt`

Step 3 - Now look for the drive where you store your operating window by listing all the contents in the directory. `ls`

Step 4 - Change directory to that derive. e.g. in my case the operating window is in Drive C `cd c`

Step 5 - Now looks for Users folder and select that. `cd Users/`

Step 6 - Select your username. `cd <username>/`

Step 7 - Now you can either create a new directory or navigate to your specific directory by doing `ls`

After this whenever you create a new file in your Ubuntu Command line, you should be able to see in your computer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `find` command to "find" files and folders on your disk.

Since your file is most likely in your home folder, first run this command, to scan the home folder:

```
find $HOME | grep "colors.txt"
```

This command will output all results matching "colors.txt". For example, it may return something like this:

```
/home/<your_username>/Desktop/colors.txt
```

If so, that is the location of your file.

If instead, the command returns no output, you may wish to try scanning the entire disk. Do note that this will take some time, especially if you have mounted volumes:

```
find / 2> /dev/null | grep "colors.txt"
```

The `2> /dev/null` will hide error output, since some directories on the root filesystem are inaccessible. However, this command should output the location of "colors.txt" on your drive. You will see multiple results if it appears more than once.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Found it and search of drive confirmed.

Comment: Not the good way to use `find`. Use `find . -iname 'foobar.txt'`